# View files in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, file, browser

I am trying to open file into web browser by writing the files into `response.write()`

This is what i am doing

```
String filePath = txtFileName.Text;
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    long FileSize = fileStream.Length; ;
    byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
    fileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)FileSize);
    fileStream.Close();

    //Now show file in the Browser
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("inline;attachment; filename={0}",filePath));
    Response.Write(Buffer);
    Response.End();
}
```

**Problem:**
Instead of showing the file into browser it gives me options to `open or save file`

I have seen some threads for this type of problems but i didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("inline;attachment; filename={0}",filePath));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + filePath);
```

Comment: Many thanks, it worked, why this "String.Format("inline;attachment; filename={0}",filePath)" was creating a problem.